# BinarySearch won't end

Tags: java, binary-search

So basically, I know a binary search is performed on an ordered list only for it to work, so here is the list i am using:

```
Integer[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

So basically it finds an integer fine, but when i put a value that isn't in the list, it doesn't seem to end! Here is my code:

```
public static <K extends Comparable<K>> boolean binarySearch(K[] list, K item) {
    int start = 0;
    int last = list.length - 1;

    while(start <= last) {
        int middle = (start + last) / 2;
        if(list[middle].equals(item))
            return true;
        else {
            if(item.compareTo(list[middle]) < 0)
                last = middle--;
            else
                start = middle++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from your code?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprits are `last = middle--;` and `start = middle++;`.

Post-increment and post-decrement operators return the *previous* value of the operand, not the updated value. So when you call `last = middle--;`, this will effectively decrease `middle` by 1 and set `last` to `middle`, *not* `middle-1`.

Let's consider you search 7 to see why it goes into an infinite loop. The item is always after the middle element so `start` is set to `middle`, which, eventually, will be the last element of the array. But since `start = middle`, it is always lower than or equal to `last`; hence you never exit. We have reached a state where `start = last = middle` repeatedly and we can never exit it.

Here, you shouldn't event be using those operators: when the item to search is before the middle element, let `last = middle-1;`; and when the item to search is after the middle element, let `start = middle+1;`.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue :) I thought they were effectively the same thing but thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the part where you're determining `middle`. In the case where `start = 4`, `last = 5`, `middle` will always be `4`. The endless loop will occur in all situations like this, where the `.5` is being truncated since this is an `int` .

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to implement your own binary search algorithm if you do not want to. The [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class provides several different implementations and chances are that you will find a suitable implementation there. For the examples mentioned there is one for `int[]` [int binarySearch(int[] a, int key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-) and one for generic objects [int binarySearch(T[] a, T key, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-T:A-T-java.util.Comparator-) that may be of interest.

Comment: I didn't downvote but this is probably because it doesn't answer the question at all. This is a comment at best.

Comment: Well, it does not solve the specific bug in the OP's sample code, but it solves the broader underlying problem of finding an item in an array by using a well-tested binary search algorithm.

Comment: Which is exactly why it would be a good _comment_ (or the start of an answer that continues to point to what the problem is in the OP's code).